# Echo 2 Arrays Lists in Shell Script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a problem with array in bash. I wish to echo 2 Arrays in a list from the fist element from the convert array til the last element. The same thing for room_minute array.

```
#! /bin/bash
#! /usr/bin/perl

declare -a data;
declare -a convert;
declare -a sala_minutos;

data=($(./Minutes.php 2> /dev/null | grep -P -w -o [0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\} | awk -v FS=/ -v OFS=/ '{print $2,$1,$3}'));

room_minutes=($(./Minutes.php 2> /dev/null | grep -oP '(?<=room: )[0-9]+'))


for ((i=0; i< ${#data[*]}; i++));
do
convert=($(date -d "${data[i]} 10:00:00" +%s));
done

echo ${convert[*]} ${room_minutes[*]}
```

Obs inside the arrays:

> data = [09/03/16 09/01/16 09/02/16 09/03/16 09/04/16 09/05/16 09/06/16 09/07/16 09/08/16 09/09/16  09/10/16 09/11/16 09/12/16 09/13/16 08/25/16 08/26/16 08/27/16 08/28/16 08/29/16 08/30/16 08/31/16]
>
> covert = [1472698800 1472785200 1472871600 1472958000  1473044400 1473130800 1473217200 1473303600 1473390000 1473476400 1473562800 1473649200 1473735600 1472094000 1472180400 1472266800 1472353200 1472439600 1472526000 1472612400]
>
> room_minutes = [7339 8748 211 15 15927 7028 34 11112 12567 686 5 13988 11279 8465 4402 60 1 10380 8078 8422]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There's quite a lot that's wrong here -- to start with, `foo=( $(bar) )` is actually a very buggy way to populate an array. For instance, if your `bar` emits `*` with whitespace surrounding it, that'll be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory. Use `read -a`, `readarray`, `mapfile`, or a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to populate your arrays.

Comment: Second, `${foo[*]}` is a buggy way to expand an array. Just as `${foo[*]}` does, it performs glob expansion -- but it also performs string-splitting. Thus, if `foo=( "first * argument" "second * argument" )`, `"${foo[@]}"` will expand to exactly two arguments (like you'd expect), but `${foo[*]}` will expand to an unpredictable number based on the value of `$IFS` and the number of files in the current directory.

Comment: Third, it's not at all clear from this question how your expected and actual results differ. Please build a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- a **minimal, complete, verifiable** example -- that anyone else can run (without needing `Minutes.php`) to see your problem, and provide both the actual and expected output.

Comment: (You're resetting `convert` every time you iterate through the `for` loop, by the way, so why would you expect it to have more than one element?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want `convert` and `room_minutes` in two columns. i've changed as little as possible to accomplish this using multiline strings and `paste` instead of arrays. the `data=` and `room_minutes=` lines are unchanged except for stripping the outermost `()`s.

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(./Minutes.php 2> /dev/null | grep -P -w -o [0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\} | awk -v FS=/ -v OFS=/ '{print $2,$1,$3}');

room_minutes=$(./Minutes.php 2> /dev/null | grep -oP '(?<=room: )[0-9]+');

convert=$(echo "$data" | xargs -I{} date -d "{} 10:00:00" +%s)

paste <(echo "$convert") <(echo "$room_minutes")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

data=($(./Minutes.php 2> /dev/null | grep -P -w -o [0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\} | awk -v FS=/ -v OFS=/ '{print $2,$1,$3}'));

room_minutes=($(./Minutes.php 2> /dev/null | grep -oP '(?<=room: )[0-9]+'));

for ((i=0; i< ${#data[@]}; i++));
do
convert=($(date -d "${data[$i]} 10:00:00" +%s));
echo -e Room_Minutes ${convert[@]} ${room_minutes[$i]}
done
```

Comment: Eh? `data` isn't an array at all here, and if you mean `data=( $(./Minutes.php ...) )`, that's buggy too -- use `readarray -t data < <(./Minutes.php ...)` to avoid glob expansion, string-splitting on non-newline characters, etc.

Comment: Thanks I've made a mistake now it is corrected!
humm using readarray -t data  I'll try that.